# Implement an interface with final fields or access fields directly?

Tags: java, performance, blackberry, java-me

Is there any advantage of NOT having a class `implement` an interface and instead use the final fields directly? For example:

```
public interface MyInterface {
    int CONST_A = 16;
    int CONST_B = 45;
}
```

Approach 1:

```
public class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    MyClass() {
        System.out.println("A = " + CONST_A);
        System.out.println("B = " + CONST_B);
    }

}
```

Approach 2:

```
public class MyClass {

    MyClass() {
        System.out.println("A = " + MyInterface.CONST_A);
        System.out.println("B = " + MyInterface.CONST_B);
    }

}
```

I was wondering if any of the approaches above has advantage of any kind over the other. One of the places this situation occurs is in Blackberry where you have your localized texts defined as an interface with keys to the strings and you need to call a system API with the key as the argument in various parts of the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is considered a bad practice to put constants in interfaces and to implements those interfaces to access the constants. The reason is, many classes could implement the interface, thus providing many access points to the same constants.

So, to answer your question, I'd rather use the second solution. Even better, I'd put the constants in a final class, so that there is only a single point of access to the constants. It'd be clearer, and would be easier to refactor.

Comment: You are right it would create many access point to those constants if many classes implement that interface, which is the case in Blackberry since many classes would need to access those strings. However I'm not yet convinced why this is a bad thing? The fields are final so all of the access points really translate to the same value. However it might create name conflicts as Emmerich has mentioned but that is not really an issue (At least in Blackberry) if an appropriate pattern is used for the constants such as TXT_xxxx.

Comment: It is more of a design issue. You must define who "owns" the constants. If they are stored in an interface implemented by many classes, the ownership is unclear : Interface.CONST, Class1.CONST, Class2.CONST... all refer to the same constant. For easier refactoring and design clarity, it's better to access it only via a single class, such as MyConsts.CONST.

Answer (score 3):

use enumeration for constants (Effective Java)

For example define like that and call `KernelError.KE_UNDEFINED_CALLER`

```
public enum KernelError {
    KE_NO_ERROR(0), KE_UNDEFINED_SESSION(1), KE_UNDEFINED_CALLER(2), KE_SESSION_EXPIRED(
            3), KE_NULL_VALUE_IN_SESSION(4), KE_N0_SUCH_METHOD(5);

    private KernelError(int errorCode) {
        setErrorCode(errorCode);

    }

    private int errorCode;

    /**
     * @return the errorCode
     */
    public int getErrorCode() {
        return errorCode;
    }

    /**
     * @param errorCode
     *            the errorCode to set
     */
    public void setErrorCode(int errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting proposal, but limited to the case of "equivalent" constants : constants that are indeed an eunmeration of possible cases. In the question, those constants can be, as an example for a thread pool, POOL_MAX_SIZE and TASK_CANCEL_DELAY. In such a case, putting both in the same enum will be counter-intuitive, and having one enum per constant seems to me particularly verbose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I learned something about enums! However in Blackberry there is no enum! Moreover you are forced to have the interface implemented the way that I showed. The question is really about only those two approaches.

Comment: Why do you prefix the name of the enums with their type? What is the benefit of this redundancy?

Comment: @aligf Thanks for your answer. I don't Blackberry platform that is why I can't comment anything on it

Comment: @mertion in order to be compatible with our oracle database. there is no any special reason

Answer (score 1):

If you defined constants in interfaces and, for example, define `MyInterface2` which has a constant `CONST_A`, they conflict. Personally I think that approach 2 is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer approach 2 as it does not pollute the namespace of the using class with all possible constants. This reduces the number of code completion choices. Also, when looking at a use of a constant, the qualified name makes it obvious that it is a constant, and where that constant is defined.

That is, I prefer

```
interface Constants {
    static int A;
    static int B;
}

void foo() {
    System.out.println(Constants.A);
}
```

to

```
interface Constants {
    static int Const_A;
    static int Const_B;
}

void foo() {
    System.out.println(Const_A);
}
```